# Multiple procedures in Oracle SQL Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, vba, adodb

**Excel version**: 2013

**SQL Oracle** with ADODB

I am rather new to ADODB and SQL. I have the following code:

```
objMyCmd.CommandText = "begin " & Chr(10) & _
"scheme1.function1(to_date('2017.01.01','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2017.03.01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'ALEX'); " & Chr(10) & "commit; " & Chr(10) & "end; "

objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

objMyCmd.Execute

objMyCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from table1"

objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

objMyCmd.Execute
```

The code in SQL interpretator would look like this:

```
begin 
scheme1.function1(to_date('2017.01.01','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2017.03.01','YYYY-MM-DD'),'ALEX'); 
commit; 
end;  

SELECT * from table1
```

When running the 2nd `objMyCmd.Execute` I get:

`[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00903: invalid table name`

I guess the problem arises from combining the first and the second procedures in a single `objMyCmd.CommandText`.

Please, help me solve this problem and make a VBA script work correctly.

Comment: Try `objMyCmd.CommandText = "{begin ...end;}"` or `objMyCmd.CommandText = "{call scheme1.function1...}`

Comment: Your date strings and date format strings look like they don't match.  Is table1 created by the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this table in your schema? 
If no - is there a public synonym ?
Try schema.table1
Maybe there is no public synonym.